# whats the absolute time interval?

Tags: absolute-value

For the time interval $1< \lvert t+1 \rvert \leq 3 $ I am trying to solve for t to get my range to plot a function.

I know $\lvert t+1 \rvert \leq 3 \iff -3\leq t+1 \leq 3 \iff -4 \leq t \leq 2$

And then $ \lvert t+1 \rvert > 1 $ becomes  $t+1 >1 $ or $t+1 <-1$. Hence $t>0$ or $t<-2$.

Then things seem to contradict and i can't figure out my time range. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is fine.  You then need to find the $t$-values that satisfy both conditions: $-4 \leq t \leq 2$ and $t \in (-\infty, -2) \cup (0, \infty)$.

Alternatively, you could consider two cases: $t + 1 \geq 0$ and $t + 1 < 0$.  When $t + 1 \geq 0$, we have that $|t + 1| = t + 1$, and thus $1 < t + 1 \leq 3$ so that $0 < t \leq 2$.  All of these values are permissible as we are assuming $t > -1$ in this range as $t + 1 > 0$.  You could deal with the other case $t + 1 < 0$ by noting that $|t + 1| = - (t + 1)$ in this range.

Comment: so i can have two different sets of intervals that can satisfy the t values?

Comment: @user1945925: I'm not sure precisely what you mean.  However, you _can_ have two different intervals which satisfy the system of inequalities.

Comment: Nice approach. +1